Find the next "consecutive-prime composite number" from a given one.
Good day all.  I am not a mathematician by a long shot. Please bear with me...
I am playing with "descending-consecutive-prime composite numbers" (I don't think that's the term).  These are numbers that contain all the prime factors from 2 until $p_n$, such that their prime factorization, say $2^{a_1} \times 3^{a_2} \times ... \times p_n^{a_n}$ have the property $1 \leq a_n \leq a_{n-1} \leq ... \leq a_1$
They tend to have really interesting patterns, especially as they become larger: $120120, 180180, 240240, 360360, 720720, 1081080, 1441440, 1801800$, etc.
I was wondering, is it at all possible to get the next "descending-consecutive-prime composite number" given the number, $n$, and its prime factorization, i.e. $n=77636318760$ with $n = 2^3 \times 3^2 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13 \times 17 \times 19 \times 23 \times 29$ without painstakingly checking each number?
I fail to see the pattern... :-(

Well $2^4\times 3^2\times.... 29$ and $2^3\times 3^3\times....29$ and $2\times 3^2\times 5^2 \times ...\times 29$ are the next few.  Do you see why?

Note that the count of all such numbers where $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=k$ is the value $p(k)$ of the partition function at $k$.

The mentioned pattern is simply a consquence of $7\cdot 11\cdot 13=1001$ and all of the numbers you are interested with $p_n\ge 13$ have the prime factors $7,11,13$ and are hence divisible by $1001$. For small multiples , this gives a clear pattern , but for larger values this pattern soon breaks down.

Is this https://oeis.org/A126098 ?

@GerryMyerson Indeed it is!  That is helpful, thank you.

If that's the right link, then the next one is $107084577600=2^63^25^2\times7\times11\times13\times17\times19\times23$

@GerryMyerson I think A126098 is not it... take for example $2^3×3^2×5^2=1800$. It fits the definition but its not in the sequence... Powers of 2 should all be there as well if I understood correctly....

The sequence is https://oeis.org/A025487

That makes the next term $77837760000 = 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 3 \times 5 \times 5 \times 5 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13$.

I don't have a set pattern but after the $n = 2^3 \times 3^2 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13 \times 17 \times 19 \times 23 \times 29$
The next one with a new prime added would be $2\times 3 \times 5 \times.... \times 29\times 31$ which will be $\frac {31}{2^2\cdot 3}\approx  2.6$ times larger.
Before that we have one that is only two times larger but $2^4\times 3\times 5 .... \times 29$.
And before that we have one that is one and a half time larger by $2^2 \times 3^3 \times 5 \times.... \times 29$.
Basically we can get larger ones but not very much larger ones by decreasing the powers of $2,3$ and increasing a power for $p_n$.
$\frac 53 = 1\frac 23$ so we can get one that is $1\frac 23$ larger by $2^3\times 3 \times 5^2 \times .... \times 29$.
And $\frac 76$ or $\frac {11}{10}$ and so on... play with it.

As I understand it, OP insists on exponents decreasing as primes increase, so anything starting $2^3\times3\times5^2$ won't fly.

Oh, I misunderstood.  Then.... well I actually don't undestand the problems. .... okay.  Well, then it's easier.  The only things less then $2\cdot....\cdot 31$ (which is $2.6$ times as big as what we've got is to increase $2$ then we have then 2 to 31.  But then we want 3 times what we had with $2^3\times 2^3 \times.... 29$.

If the link in my comment gives the right sequence, then the next one is $107084577600=2^63^25^2\times7\times11\times13\times17\times19\times23$
